# Chrome extensions onreadystatechange function doesn't execute

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension tried to log me in on a certain website when a login button is present. I now want to add a check if the login failed, so the script doesnt loop and instead I can handle it in some other way. My problem is that the check never actually happens.

I want to check by looking for an auth cookie that is set in the responseheader, but it doesn't work, because nothing in the function() actually executes.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://loginpage.com/login?login=1&password=2", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
var cookies = xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

if(cookies.includes("auth=")) {
    everythingworks();
} else {
    wrongcredentials();
}
}
};
```

Comment: You're using **synchronous mode** (`false` in the third parameter) so your request completes in `xhr.send()` which means the state doesn't change afterwards.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Now it's working but having the error "refused to get unsafe header". Time for more research